# PHP Notice: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object. How to resolve?

Tags: php, api, curl

I am using cURL and PHP to make a request to a test API to return a list of users but I get the following error:

PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Not sure where I am going wrong.

Here is my code

```
<?php
    // I am using the JSONPlaceholder website as a test API
    $url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

    // Initial a new cURL session
    $request = curl_init($url);
    
    // Return request as string
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    
    // Run cURL / execute http request
    $response = curl_exec($request);

    // Close the cURL resource
    curl_close($request);

if ($response === false) {
    print "Could not make successful request\n";
} else {
    $response = json_decode($response);
    print $response->id . "\n";
    print $response->name . "\n";
    print $response->username . "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: What is `$response` before the decode?

Comment: A list of users in JSON format

Comment: By the looks of it, that API returns an array of objects. So you can't access it through `$response->id`, but you have to access which user/at which index you want to print it, i.e. `$response[0]->id`

Comment: Right, so which user do you want?  If all, then loop through them.

Comment: A good idea would be to validate the response e.g. by checking if it is a valid json and contains expected values, before attempting to access them. Otherwise, the API may change and break your application.

Comment: Yes I need to output them all as a simple html page :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to loop through the response:

```
if ($response === false) {
    print "Could not make successful request\n";
} else {
    $response = json_decode($response);

    foreach ($response as $item) {
        print $item->id . "\n";
        print $item->name . "\n";
        print $item->username . "\n";
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. This is what I was looking for. Is there a way I can output the JSON data to a simple HTML file?

Comment: yeah, you can echo the vars inside html tags with <?php // code here ?> blocks, for example: <b><?php echo $item->name; ?></b>